# jsf2.2.9 incompatible with servlet-api2.5?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm working with jsf2.2.9 and my weblogic container work with javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar
but sometime I have this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.Cookie.setHttpOnly(Z)V
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.addResponseCookie(Unknown Source)
```

so I see in source code of jsf2.2.9 this:

```
 switch (2.$SwitchMap$com$sun$faces$context$ExternalContextImpl$ALLOWABLE_COOKIE_PROPERTIES[localALLOWABLE_COOKIE_PROPERTIES.ordinal()])
    {
    case 1:
      localCookie.setDomain((String)localObject);
      break;
    case 2:
      localCookie.setMaxAge(((Integer)localObject).intValue());
      break;
    case 3:
      localCookie.setPath((String)localObject);
      break;
    case 4:
      localCookie.setSecure(((Boolean)localObject).booleanValue());
      break;
    case 5:
      localCookie.setHttpOnly(((Boolean)localObject).booleanValue());
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
```

and **setHttpOnly** not exist in javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar :( 
it exist in servlet-api3.0 i guess.

I can't upgrade my weblogic because other application work with it. 
what can i do to resolve this problem without pass to jsf2.1 (because 2.1 don't call localCookie.setHttpOnly, it's appear in version beetween 2.1.3 and 2.2.0) and now all development is finish and no one have this error before :(

Comment: http://myfaces.apache.org/core22/ and http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2014/04/what-should-be-minimum-dependency.html, say 2.5 is the minimum but on http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info it states _"JSF 2.2 requires a minimum of **Servlet 3.0**, because of the new file upload component which is internally using the standard Servlet 3.0 API without the need for 3rd party libraries. It requires a minimum of Java 1.6."_ So it might be that if you don't need the fileUpload, you should be able to use 2.5, but obviously not...

Comment: Well at the very least upgrade JSF to the latest patch version, to rule out you're running into a regression bug that has already been solved

Comment: hello @Gimby, in wich version are tou talking about?

Comment: i see this :  case 5:
          if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINEST))
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "Unable to set httpOnly on cookie.  Method not present in Servlet 2.5"); break; but i m not using this version : https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.1.29-05-SNAPSHOT/ does an official version in 2.2 or superior can contain this modification to be compatible with servlet 2.5?

Comment: @MançauxPierre-Alexandre the one marked as the latest version on the javaserver-faces.net main page of course, or the last version you can find in the maven repositories.